# A small question about the change() function,how to understand the process about it?

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning the basic usage of python,and I'm confusing about how the variable runs in a practice question. Here are the code below:

```
x = 1
def change(a):
  a = x + 1
  print(x)
change(x) 

x = 1
def change(a)
  x = x + 1
  print(x)
change(x)
```

This is how I think the process:
in the first code:change(x) means: x = x + 1  -  print （x）  -  output:2
but in fact the result is 1.So the real process is: x(symbol in the function) = x(global variable) + 1, print(x), this x is the global variable.
is that right?

in the second code,I think still the output should be 2,but it shows me that UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
so in the python,we can't use function to change the global variable?

Answer (score 0):

Inside a function, you can read global variables but you cannot modify them without explicitly declaring them as `global` like this:

```
x = 1
def change(a):
  global x # <- this is required since you're assigning a new value to x
  x = x + 1
  print(x)
change(x)
```

In the first case, with `a = x + 1`, the global declaration is not required since you're only reading the value of `x`, not modifying it. Also, the output is 1 in the first case, since you're printing `x` not `a`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  But what's the difference between the **x** in the code? If I use `change(x)` to execute the function. Is the **x** in the parentheses is just a symbol? so the function should be : x = x + 1. the **x** in the right should be the global variable, what's the first **x** ? a symbol too ?